# Can I double boot if my pc does not have virtualization?

Tags: linux, boot

I have an Lenovo Ideapad S400, which does not have virtualization and has only one hard drive.

Wishing to install Linux, I tried first Virtualbox but failed because virtualization was required.

My current project is to dual boot Linux. I have researched but have not found anything useful.

I will be grateful for any information.

Comment: yes, you can dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

"Dual boot" refers to when you have 2 bare-metal operating systems on the same system.  You can do the 1-OS-per-disk, or partition/repartition one disk.

What you may look into is installing Linux on a USB drive and booting off of that.  While Linux will run slower off of a USB drive (but really not a big issue if your laptop and USB drive are both USB 3.0), it cause the least disruption to your current Windows install.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary OS is windows, then just download any Linux version and install it from booting laptop with DVD or USB. It will show a menu and guide you. While installing Linux it will prompt you to make new partition from free space available in your HDD.

Comment: Warning: If the Linux installer DOESN'T  ask you if you want to setup a dual-boot with the existing Windows system, then do NOT continue. In some situations (e..g Windows disk has encryption) the Linux installer may think it is installing to an empty disk. This is a generic problem that affects every non-Microsoft OS trying to co-exist with Windows.